# How to prompt a reset password after first login

Tags: node-red

We have a requirement that custom nodes are delivered as container image which is built on top of node-red base image.
For security reasons, we added user in node-red with default credentials which will be shared securely (via email).

But however we want to enforce the user to reset the password once he login with default credentials successfully.
is there any way to trigger the password reset for that particular user when he login next-time or after successfully login for first time? Or does node-red any equivalent similar futures like onetime password already ? It would be really helpful if we get any ideas/solution to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with the built in Admin Auth plugin, the user details and hashed password are stored in the `settings.js` file which can not (ok, it could but it's a very bad idea) be changed by the running instance of Node-RED.

Also it would depend on if a volume has been mounted on `/data` directory to if any changes would be persisted across a container restart.

You will do better to implement a custom Admin Auth plugin that stores the credential details elsewhere.

But there is also no mechanism in the Node-RED front end to do password updates.